# Fill the columns of a table with data from an specific cell on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

Is it possible? I have a lot of inventory lists, one per store and the stores have an Id, I need to get the store Id and copy on the column next to the information, it could be with temporalized tables I guess, for example:

I wanto to transform this:

```
Col1    Col2  Col3
-------------------
NULL    NULL  NULL
Store   5537  NULL
NULL    NULL  NULL
stuff1   $57     2
stuff2   $34     5
stuff3   $13     1
stuff4   $28     2
```

Into this:

```
Col1    Col2  Col3  Col4
------------------------
NULL    NULL  NULL  5537
Store   5537  NULL  5537
NULL    NULL  NULL  5537
stuff1   $57     2  5537
stuff2   $34     5  5537
stuff3   $13     1  5537
stuff4   $28     2  5537
```

By grabbing the numbre from the col2,row2 from the original table.
Please help! I know maybe this is not the best way to fill a database by repeating all the times the number but my boss wants it that way. So please help me with some ideas.

Comment: how do you know where the `stuffN` stop from store 5537 and store 5538 starts?

Comment: The upload is from one by one file so, there aren't 5538 until I upload another file. The 5537 should be on any row in the Col 4 until the "end of file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3, a.Col2 AS Col4 
FROM TableName t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Col2 FROM TableName WHERE Col1 = 'Store') a
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do:

`SELECT tabla_nueva.f1, tabla_nueva.f2, tabla_nueva.f3, tabla_nueva.f4, tabla_nueva.f5, substring(tabla_nueva.F4,1,4) AS CR
FROM tabla_nueva
CROSS APPLY (SELECT tabla_nueva.F4 FROM tabla_nueva WHERE tabla_nueva.F1 like 'SUC%') A` 

but it just repeat all the column and not the number that I want.

Comment: @DanielPalomino, without the actual data it's hard to say what is going on wrong in your query. Add some data to your question that will fail for your query and I will try to help you. May be you should notice alias `a` in  my query and how I select `a.Col2` and not `TabbleName.Col2`